# What is the maximum number of columns and rows of cards a 2-player physical TCG layout could reasonably have?

Tags: game-design, playing-cards, tournament, two-player, board-size

Some TCGs have layouts of pre-defined slots in which cards are placed during gameplay.  Others do not (but may or may not have limits on the number of cards which may be in play simultaneously).  This question is mainly focused on TCGs of the former classification.  I want to know how many columns and rows of cards a TCG layout could reasonably have before running into space bottlenecks.  Yu-Gi-Oh! is currently 7 x 5 (this playmat is for both players)...

[image]

...and has been 7 x 6 in the past (this playmat is for a single player)...

[image]

The first consideration is how much table-space length and width are reasonable to assume available per pair of players at most hobby shops, hotels, conversion centers, etc., in which tournaments could be organized.  Do stores typically purchase large quantities of tables after they decide to organize TCG tournaments specifically for that purpose, or already have them on hand?  Even if the former, consideration of how much physical space is available in the aisles of most stores, or in the stores themselves, may have some bearing on the answer to the question (although the latter would mainly just trade off with the store's capacity).

The other consideration is how small each card may reasonably be made.  This obviously depends on the amount of information which needs to be stored on them.  Yu-Gi-Oh! uses smaller cards than most TCGs, and standardization issues related to things like card sleeves iron themselves out, but at some size, I'm sure cards become hard to shuffle, or otherwise create new problems.  Have there been successful TCGs which use smaller cards than Yu-Gi-Oh! without problems?  Have any tried but run into serious problems due to the small card size?

What other considerations are there, if any, when choosing the size of cards and layout of a playmat for a TCG?

Comment: Hi and welcome to this SE. Usually questions that ask for lists of things (or otherwise don't have "a correct answer" or "are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers") are not suitable here. See https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson It is not clear to me that the question crosses any lines moreso than is generally accepted on this site, and the information at the link is too generic to explain it.  For example, questions about complex game strategy are positively received, even though well-reasoned heuristics must often substitute for a unique, mathematically-provable answer.  I don't see this question as asking for a list; there certainly are multiple question marks in it, but they all tie together into a single overarching question.  I want to know the capacity for card slots in a 2-player physical TCG.

Comment: Oh, for sure. Many older questions definitely push the guidelines. And this may fit as well. That why I didn't actually mark it for closure. That said, "What other considerations are there?" is clearly list-oriented (as well as being one of several questions).